# Updating values with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Let's assume I have a table like that

```
END

id     rank    degree
1       4        3
2       3        3


**rank 4 has 4 degrees.
**rank 3 has 4 degrees.
```

And we will assume that each rank has some number of degrees. I will assume that rank 3 has 4 degrees.

And I want that, when I increase a degree that is the maximum for the current rank, the rank increases by 1 and the degree resets back to 1. For example, I want to increase the degree of the id 2 in the above table by 1. As a result, the rank should be 4 and the degree should be 1.

How can I make that update efficiently in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: I've read your question 4 times and I still don't understand it ! how is rank calculated ?

Comment: Wat is your requirement.?

Comment: assume ranks from 1 -> 6
and let's assume that every rank have 5 degrees 

if the degree reached 5 the rank will be increased by 1 

got it?

Comment: Do you have more detail about what you want to do cause i don't see the problem there. if it's too complex i could imagine to create a trigger on update on the same table updating the degree from inserted. But i don't see the use at this moment

Comment: I want each time to increase the degrees by 1 ok? 
and in the same time I want to increase the rank by 1 if the degrees became 5 !! got it???

Comment: Listen pal these people are offering free help for what I assume is one of your homework questions. I would highly recommend you not get so snippy with them when they are asking for clarification to your problem.

Comment: @SELECT_UPDATE: You want to increase degree but you've mentioned _"rank will be 4 and the degree will back to 1"_. That suggests that you actually want to increase rank and set degree back to 1.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I meant by that ( that when the degree reached the max number of degrees which is 4 or 5 as you want I want the rank now to be increased and the degree will back to 1?? got me?

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. I've tried to rephrase some parts to make the question clearer. Feel free to add further corrections or roll it back.

Comment: And, of course, your example is confusing, because the data sample contains two rows with rank=3, one with degree=5 and the other with degree=4, and yet you've chosen to assume that rank 3 has 4 degrees, not 5. I would probably either change the example to the other rank 3 row or corrected the degree 5 row to be a different rank. (But to actually change that would seem to me too much of an edit on my side, as I'm not the author of the question, so it's up to you.)

Comment: @AndriyM thanks for your edit,

I added 2 ranks of 3 so I can explain that I want to make changes in all of the ranks not only one rank.

I will remove the third row So it can be more clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, but then you should also correct corresponding references in the description, because the example is about id 3 which now doesn't exist.

Comment: I was doing that already, thanks :) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a reference table containing information about the maximum degree for every supported rank (let's call it `dbo.ranks`), something like this:

```
rank  maxdegree
----  ---------
1     3
2     4
3     5
4     4
...   ...
```

where `maxdegree` is assumed to be an integer greater than 0, then here's how you could use it:

```
UPDATE t
SET
  t.rank   += t.degree / r.maxdegree,
  t.degree += t.degree % r.maxdegree + 1
FROM dbo.atable AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.ranks AS r
ON t.rank = r.rank
;
```

where `dbo.atable` is assumed to be the name of the table to update.

Note that this query is only intended for increasing by 1. If you want it to be able to increase `degree` by an arbitrary number, you will need to make more substantial changes than just replacing `1` in the `+ 1` bit.

Also, this query will not work correctly with some cases of invalid data in your table (like degrees greater than the corresponding maximums), so make sure you've removed any anomalies in your data before trying to use this.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to update all rows with the same rank of the one with `id=3`.

```
UPDATE t SET t.rank = t.rank + 1, t.degree = 1
FROM tableName t
WHERE rank  = (SELECT rank FROM tableName t2 WHERE id=@id)
```

Comment: great, thanks.

is the perforamnce of making a select statement in the update method is good ? or what?

Comment: @SELECT_UPDATE: the performance depends on many things like your indices. Have a look: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/ In general, it's [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)(optimizable) hence efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
update t
    set degree = (case when degree = 5 then 1 else degree + 1 end),
        rank = (case when degree = 5 then rank + 1 else rank end)
    where id = 3;
```

Comment: I have made the same and it worked before.

my question is if the id is unknown and I want to make these changes on the whole table?

Comment: @SELECT_UPDATE . . . Then remove the `where` condition.